# sql server LIMIT with where but include at least once

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, where-clause

I have a simple query like this:

```
SELECT subs.id_number, 
       op.dtupdated as dtopened
FROM subscribers AS subs
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages AS msg
ON msg.id_number = subs.id_number
LEFT JOIN email_opens AS op
ON op.message_id = msg.message_id
WHERE op.dtupdated  > dateadd(month,-3,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Basically I'm trying to get all the records in a table that tracks when an email was opened (email_opens) which is associated to subscribers by the id_number field. I want to get all email opens within the past 3 months and the associated id_number, but I also want to get include at least once, all id-numbers in the subscribers table.

The problem is my where clause eliminates all records that never had any open emails in the past 3 months, but i want to include one record with id_number and "NULL" as dtopened for subscribers who havent any opens.

I tried left outer join, union (which works but then I have duplicates), and I just cant seem to find out how to do this. Im sure there has to be a simple way and I just havent had enough coffee yet.

Answer (score 0):

Checking `op.dtupdated` in the `WHERE` clause means the records that don't match get filtered out. If you do that in your `ON` clause of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead, you'll get at least one row for each record on `subscribers`:

```
SELECT subs.id_number
    ,op.dtupdated AS dtopened
FROM subscribers AS subs
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages AS msg ON msg.id_number = subs.id_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN email_opens AS op ON op.message_id = msg.message_id
    AND op.dtupdated > dateadd(month, - 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: This query is taking forever to execute. If I do a simple query like:

`SELECT
subs.id_number, op.dtupdated as dtopened
FROM subscribers AS subs
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
messages AS msg
ON msg.id_number = subs.id_number
LEFT JOIN
email_opens AS op
ON op.message_id = msg.message_id
WHERE op.dtupdated  > dateadd(month,-3,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
UNION
SELECT id_number, NULL as dtopened
FROM subscribers
`

That only takes a few seconds.. the problem is ill get duplicates